# Does Chipmunk support continuous collision detection yet?

Tags: chipmunk, physics-engine

I've been a Box2D user, but now I'm looking into Chipmunk.  I don't think I want to leave my CCD behind though.  Sources I'm finding all seem to indicate that Chipmunk does not implement CCD, but these sources are also all over a year old.  I saw somebody mention someplace that the Chipmunk author might implement CCD after all, but it wasn't clear how likely that was to happen.

So, has it been implemented?

I can't ask this in the Chipmunk forum because registration is disabled there at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

I have a branch where I've been experimenting with speculative contacts to provide CCD on and off for well over a year, but it's definitely not usable. In a lot of cases, I think you'll find that CCD is not worth the extra cost (which can be quite significant in some cases). Bullets are usually better implemented as ray or circle casts. Chipmunk's higher performance generally means you can decrease the simulation step size by several factors to avoid tunneling while greatly increasing the simulation quality as a side effect.

Sorry about the forums. The spam problem has been getting worse and worse, and I didn't want to deal with it last week while on vacation.

Comment: I don't really know that CCD is important in my case, but I feel like it is, for better or for worse.  My tentative plan is to try to alter Box2D to make its CCD strategy less simplistic and more efficient; specifically, I don't like how it arbitrarily considers CCD to be important for all "bullets" and all static bodies, and unimportant for everything else.  But it's possible that I will just end up using Chipmunk instead in the long run, for one reason or another.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @slembcke is there any change now? Is chipmunk 7 supports CCD?

Comment: @Kowalski Sorry. No change, and currently no plans to. Too many other projects to work on. ;)

Comment: @slembcke Thanks. Should I use box2D  if I really want CCD?

Comment: Other than the advice I gave above, if CCD is a must-have features then go for Box2D. Chipmunk makes certain complexity/performance tradeoffs, and you won't hurt my feelings if Box2D made better choices for your use case. ;)